# Broadcast SMS parsing

Tags: sms, broadcast

I receive from network Broadcast SMS with 88 bytes of data, even if I has sent 10 bytes.
I want to know the structure of these 88 bytes.
Where in those data is the data itself and where is header?

Shmuel

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for, but [see here for the SMS message format](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/)